# radio button value by jquery

Tags: jquery, button, radio-button

I have a small piece of code like:

```
<?php while($plan = mysql_fetch_array($plan_values)){?>
         <input type="radio"  name="bus_plan" value="<?php echo $plan['plan_id']; ?>" />
         <a href="plan-tariff.php?plan_name=<?php echo $plan['plan_name']; ?>" target="_blank">
               <span class="radiotxt"><?php echo $plan['plan_name']; ?></span>
         </a>
         <br clear="all" />
<?php } ?>
```

By the above while condition I am getting three radio buttons whose values are namely 1,2 and 8 .
Now my question is how to get the value of radio button while I am checking any one of the above buttons.

Comment: You can use the jquery code to read the radio button value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in the head section of your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[name=bus_plan]").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
</script>
```

When you click on any radio button this code will promt you the value of that radio button. Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: it is working. but I use another js file named as "jquery.bxSlider.min.js". For that it is conflictiing. When I remove this jquery.bxSlider.min.js and put jquery-1.7.2.js then it is working. Is there any option so that two js files will work properly without hampering anything?

Comment: This link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ might help you. You can also try to change the ordering sequence of my code with your included javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio[name=bus_plan]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<input type="radio"  name="bus_plan" id="smallBtn" value="1" onClick="alert(this.value)"  />
<input type="radio"  name="bus_plan" id="smallBtn" value="2" onClick="alert(this.value)" />
<input type="radio"  name="bus_plan" id="smallBtn" value="8" onClick="alert(this.value)"  />
```

Or you can create function for this in place of `alert`
[TryThis](http://jsfiddle.net/DpT6f/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/4haQQ/

Remember to include the JQuery library first and wrap your jquery code in opening tags like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//CODE HERE
});
```